# An understanding of something in python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, socks

So I have programmed a Socks5 server with help from a youtube video.
There is one thing I don't understand and hoping to get help with it.

```
    def run(self, host, port):
        #gives it specifications, Family ip and TCP
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind((host, port))
        #ip and port to listen to
        s.listen()

        print("* Socks5 proxy server is running on {}:{}".format(host, port))

        while True:
            #3 way handshake when someone connects - TCP
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            #tupple of ip and port
            print("* new connection from {}".format(addr))
            #calling the handle_client function: handle_client(conn),conn is a socket type
            print(conn)
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(conn,))
            t.start()


    def handle_client(self, connection):
        version, nmethods = connection.recv(2)
        # get available methods [0, 1, 2]
        methods = self.get_available_methods(nmethods, connection)
        print(methods)
```

So what I don't understand in this code is this line: `version, nmethods = connection.recv(2)`.
The version is the version of socks which is 5. But the methods I don't understand. methods of what? how does it know how many methods it have and to what thing does it even have methods????
Need help, Thank you!

Comment: It is unclear for me what exactly you don't understand. The meaning of the header fields is clearly documented in the SOCKS5 standard - see [RFC 1928](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1928) section 3..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connection.recv(2)` means receive (up to) two bytes ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv)). So, two bytes are returned, and you're setting `version` to the value of the first byte, and `nmethods` to the value of the second byte.

Here's an example:

```
a = b'hi' # a is a bytes object

b, c = a # b and c are ints

print(b, c)
# output: 104 105
```

So, as for what `version` and `nmethods` mean - that's just something specific to this program I think. I'm not super familiar with sockets though. I would guess that `nmethods` means "number of methods", considering that it's used in `get_available_methods()` later. As for how it knows the number of methods, whatever those methods are, you'd just have to see the code that sends that data.

Comment: `connection.recv(2)` means receive **up to** two bytes. It may return one byte. If you think I'm being pedantic here, check out the questions tagged with the python and socket tags. The **majority** of them get this distinction critically wrong.